# Java/Ubuntu Config

Tags: java, linux

I am a brand-new Ubuntu user trying to manually install Java. I am trying to avoid using **apt-get** or Synaptic to do all the work for me, because I want to really understand the process of configuring a JDK on Ubuntu, even if it is more difficult and takes longer.

I downloaded the JDK binary to my /home/myUsername/Downloads directory, and then moved it to /opt/java because that is where I would like my Java to be based out of.

It looks like there are some basic UNIX-like configs I need to do manually, and I'm not sure what they are, how to do them, and in what order.  Things, perhaps, such as setting the PATH and CLASSPATH env variables in the .bashrc file.

Can someone give me a good account of all the steps from taking a JDK binary into a fully-installed Java system, so that I may run tools such as **java** or **javac**?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java installation issues on Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579156/java-installation-issues-on-ubuntu)

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1113039

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Learning how to do it over Ubuntu may not help you be able to do it on a different platform.

Comment: I am creating this thread because another member suggested I should create one.  Last thread was centering on Java, this is more of a UNIX config question.

Comment: I suggest you just use synaptec. I know you want to learn to do this stuff manually, but you should just use the system and get familiar with it before jumping into a lot of the details.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is add a java.sh to the /etc/profile.d directory which add /opt/java/current/bin (Where my javac etc are) to the PATH

That's all I have every needed to do.  Some applications like to have JAVA_HOME or JDK_HOME set as well.

EDIT: If you want to add a java.sh file it looks like

```
export PATH=%PATH%;/opt/java/current/bin
```

The reason I use java.sh is it is a drop in file, you don't have to alter any existing file and you can copy it from one system to another/one version of Unix to another.

Comment: New to *nix, how do I add the directory of my choice to the PATH? Like PATH = PATH + /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_23? What should the contents of java.sh look like to accomplish this?

Comment: You can read about that here `https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables`. The answer to to that question entirely depends on a lot of things about your system. In Ubuntu, USUALLY you want to put path modifications in `/etc/profile`.