# Installing Java 1.8 on Ubuntu Linux from Binary

Tags: java, linux, oracle, ubuntu

Oracle hosts a page on [how to install Java 1.8 from the binary](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml)

I was able to do the following -

Download the x64 `tar.gz` on the Oracle Downloads page.

Create my directory and move the file there

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/java
sudo mv ~/Downloads/jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz .
```

And unpack it

```
sudo tar zxvf jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

The binary itself works, because I can call it using the absolute path

```
> /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

But I can't call it standalone

```
> java -version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.7-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Even setting `$JAVA_HOME` as that directory didn't work. Is there a step I'm missing? Does it need to be added to my `$PATH`?

**Edit:** I'm aware I could probably install java with `sudo apt-get install`. I ran into some trouble there in that I wasn't able to `apt-get update` because of some `404` errors. I'd rather handle that as a separate question/post.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to "update-alternatives". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579156/java-installation-issues-on-ubuntu?rq=1

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick :) Basically added that whole `bin` directory to the end of my `$PATH`

Comment: @Thilo you can't use 'update-alternatives' here because the version is not in the path yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have just extracted the binary file but you didn't set `JAVA_HOME`.
First set the `JAVA_HOME` in your profile i.e. in `~/.bashrc` file.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_45
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Reload the `~/.bashrc` file as

`> source ~/.bashrc` press enter

Then try again.

```
> java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Thanks! Credit to user Thilo above for also providing/linking to the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use update alternatives not using JAVA_HOME. I downloaded the latest tarball **jdk-8u162-linux-x64.tar.gz** into a subdirectory **./src**. I've also set up **/opt** so that it is owned by me, otherwise you need to use sudo for the untarring of the .tar.gz file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

MAJOR_VERSION=8
ORACLE_BUILD_VERSION=162

JDK_TARBALL_VERSION=8u${ORACLE_BUILD_VERSION}-linux-x64
JDK_VERSION=1.${MAJOR_VERSION}.0_${ORACLE_BUILD_VERSION}
PRIORITY="10${MAJOR_VERSION}1"

cd src && tar xzf jdk-${JDK_TARBALL_VERSION}.tar.gz -C /opt/jdk

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk${JDK_VERSION}/bin/java ${PRIORITY}
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk/jdk${JDK_VERSION}/bin/javac ${PRIORITY}

echo "Checking: alternatives on java and javac"
sudo update-alternatives --display java
sudo update-alternatives --display javac

echo "Running: java -version"
java -version
```

I've included build 162 since this is much more recent that 45 in your message. This script above should be provided to everyone in the field of development since we can see currently that oracle-java8-installer for Debian and Ubuntu is broken as of yesterday. It might be fixed in a few days but this script will always work.

The **priority** value in the script is really important since you must override existing priority of the installed package. I've set it to use the major version to be installed. This priority would only fail if you have openjdk version 9 installed.